# Program started with Task Scheduler can't open file for writing

Tags: windows, file-permissions, scheduled-task

i have a C# program that executes some commands and writes output to a txt file. It has to run indefinitely so i added it to Task Scheduler to start it every ten minutes if it isn't running already. This task has highest privileges.

The problem is if the program is started by the Task Scheduler it can't write to the log file. If i start it normally there are no problems. I searched around the net but couldn't find an answer and i can't seem to debug this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem...

Comment: @Lenniey user i logged in has every permission on both the log file and the program executable. I also put a tick into "Run with highest privileges" in Task Scheduler.

Comment: The avoid any kind of permission problem: Change the executing account to "SYSTEM" and tick "Run wether user is logged on or not". Should work in any case if only local resources are used

Comment: @maltmann Or just set the correct directory / file / execution permissions ;)

Comment: @Lenniey sure. but the system-way can be useful as an exclusion test

Comment: @maltmann Nothing against an exclusion test! But sadly "tests" often stay in "production" forever

Answer (score 0):

This code will help for the error log.
You have to add this code in the catch block.

```
enter code here
catch(Exception ex){
 string file = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + "errorlog.txt";
                        tw = new StreamWriter(file, false);
                        tw.Write(ex.Message);
                        tw.Close();}
```